# ADO.NET POCO with SQLite database - alter table instead of drop table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite, ado.net

relating to this [msdn sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Demo-of-ADONET-POCO-with-140ad3ad) I've build a application which generates the database from a model. Now I think about the fact that I have a filled database and don't want to drop all tables because of the losing of my data. Is there a possibility to generate a "alter table" version of thequery instead of a "drop table" version?

regards Chris

Answer (score 0):

If you've made changes to models and want those changes to be reflected in your database without losing data you should look at using [Entity Framework Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621).

The tutorial in the link provides a good walk-through.

---

[Migration using model first approach in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920491/migration-using-model-first-approach-in-entity-framework)

Comment: I'm using model-first and I think here is the regimentation of the migrations possibility from you link.

Comment: Sorry should have looked at your link. See edited answer I've linked to a similar question with an answer from a reputable user.

Comment: No MigrationSqlGenerator found for provider 'System.Data.SQLite'. Use the SetSqlGenerator method in the target migrations configuration class to register additional SQL generators.